# как менять статусы в определённом порядке?

Tags: java

задача: есть приложение, там гора статусов, если стоит текущий статус, то можно поменять только на один из определённых статусов: вопрос как обычно такое реализовывать?

Comment: не охото лепить гору иф елсов

Comment: Используйте enum

Comment: @miron ну enum сильно не поменяешь в runtime. Поэтому лучше отдельный класс и его в коллекцию или коллекцию из string. Что нибудь из Set, чтобы были уникальные значения

Comment: @vadtel здрасьте, кто ж сказал, что нужно в runtime какие-то новые статусы добавлять? "можно поменять только на один из определённых статусов" - под это идеально подходит enum.

Comment: @miron ну статусы дело такое. Сегодня не надо, а завтра уже надо. Мое личное мнение  - лучше универсально. Хотя если отталкиваться от вопроса, то вы правы, enum отлично.

Comment: очень понравился ответ про конечные автоматы, на примере энумератора можно в бд завести объект правило статуса - первое поле статус второе поле лист статусов  (связь многие к одному и многие ко многим) получится таблица конечного автомата

Comment: @vadtel можно и расширить, недавно, кстати, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Решил использованием классов с статическими final полями. Когда нужно добавить группу статусов - наследуемся от основного класса, и создаем статусы в виде объектов основного класса. Невероятная гибкость, жаль, что enum такого не поддерживает. Приходится самому делать.

Answer (score 4):

При помощи возможностей enum можно соорудить достаточно гибкую конструкцию.

```
 enum Input {
  NICKEL, QUARTER, DOLLAR,
  TOOTHPASTE, CHIPS, SODA, SOAP
}

enum Category {
MONEY(NICKEL, QUARTER, DOLLAR),
ITEM(TOOTHPASTE, CHIPS, SODA, SOAP)

private Input[] values;

Category(Input... types) {values = types;}

private static EnumMap<Input, Category> categories = new EnumMap(Input.class);

static {
 for (Category c: Category.class.getEnumConstants())
  for (Input type: c.values)
   categories.put(type, c);
}

public static Category categorize(Input input) {
 return categories.get(input);
}

}
```

Ну и, в конечном итоге, использовать метод `categorize()` для определения конкретных типов состояний. И наоборот, можно добавить метод получения состояний для конкретной категории.